# Insert data into MYSQL using jquery modal form

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I have a page shown below that displays a list of user records from a database with a button. When I clicked on that button display a jquery modal form with a form that allows someone to enter their user information.

My problem is when I click on the '*Add New User*' button on the modal form the data should be insert to the database. But that data is not going to database.

This is the code in users.php page with modal form dialog

```
 <body>

    <h1>User Management System</h1>

    <div id="manage_user">
        <form action="" method="">

           // Here I display a table with user details.................

            <button id="FormSubmit">Add New User</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="dialog" class="new_user_dialog_box" title="Add New User">
        <p>Fill this form with your details and click on 'Add New User' button to register.</p>

        <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

        <div id="new_user_form">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" /></td>
                </tr>               
                <tr>
                    <td>Address :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="address" value="" id="address" /></td>
                </tr>               
                <tr>
                    <td>City :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="city" value="" id="city" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

 </body>
```

The Javascript/jQuery script is

```
        if ( bValid) { 

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
                url: "process.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
                dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
                data:bValid, //Form variables
                success:function(response){
                    //on success, hide  element user wants to delete.
                    //$('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut("slow");
                },
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    //On error, we alert user
                alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
            $(this).dialog("close");                    
        }
```

Any help here is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: There are several steps between clicking the button and data being inserted into the database.  Which step is failing?  Is the AJAX call being made to the server?  Does it contain the expected data?  What is the server's response?  Is the PHP code being executed as expected?  Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?  Are there any errors in the PHP logs?

Comment: @David thanks for response. There is not any errors in JavaScript console. After completing form fields from modal form dialog it is closing and don't where data is going'

Comment: There is nothing on PHP errors log also

Comment: If you're not familiar with browser debugging tools, this is a good time to familiarize yourself with them.  Using something like Chrome developer tools or Firebug (whatever browser you use should have something), monitor the requests and responses (perhaps on a tab called "net" or "network activity" or something of that nature).  This will tell you if anything is actually being sent to the server, what exactly is being sent, and what the server's response is.

Comment: In `All` menu on firebug there is a tab called `response` and there is a message like this `error in post array`

Comment: What is your POST array?  It looks like the "data" you're trying to send in the AJAX call is a variable called `bValue`, which appears to only be a boolean.  You should be sending key/value pairs for the form elements.

Comment: In my post array should be `$_POST['name'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['city']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not actually sending data in your POST.  Look at this line in your AJAX call:

```
data:bValid, //Form variables
```

What is `bValid`?  From the looks of the code above that line, it's just a boolean.  But the `data` in an AJAX POST needs to contain key/value pairs corresponding to the form elements.  Try something like this instead:

```
dataType: 'JSON',
data: { name: $('#name').val(), address: $('#address').val(), city: $('#city').val() }
```

This would send a JSON object of key/value pairs, which get their values from the HTML elements with the ids `name`, `address`, and `city` in your form.

Comment: I just tried it and there is an alert `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character`

Comment: Then I found data is going to database. But not display in users.php page on the same time. If data is make to display I need to reload the page.

Comment: Can I know the reason for this? Thank you.

Comment: @TNK: Well, are you updating the page?  AJAX requests don't reload the page, so any updates to the page content will need to be done manually.  Conversely, reloading the page will also update the content.

Comment: @TNK: No.  If you have additional specific questions then you can create a new question on Stack Overflow for that purpose.  But if you're looking for someone to teach you web development then that's too broad for the scope of Stack Overflow.  I'll be happy to help with specific additional questions, but it sounds like what you need is to find some beginner tutorials on PHP, JavaScript, jQuery, web development in general.  And Stack Overflow doesn't really provide that.  The scope of this comment thread has already exceeded the scope of the original question.

Comment: Ok. David, then tell me what did you mean 'are you updating the page?' in your earlier comment?

Comment: @TNK: You said that when you make the AJAX call to send data to the server, that data isn't shown in the page you're currently viewing.  Well, there's no reason that it would unless you put it there.  Generally you would update the current page in the `success` function of the AJAX call.  The rest of the page has no knowledge of the result of the AJAX call.  You have to update page elements when you want them to change, either in JavaScript on the client side or in PHP on the server-side (the latter of which requires reloading the page).

Comment: Can you kindly tell me how I update `success` function to update user details without reloading the page? Thank you

Comment: @TNK: You already have a `success` function in your AJAX call, it's just empty.  That's where you'd put code to respond to a successful AJAX call.  (Conversely, your empty `error` function would be where you'd respond to an error in the AJAX call.)  In your HTML you state that there is a "table with user details."  I imagine what you want to do is add a row to that table and put the data from the form in that row.  As for the details on *how* to do that, do some research and, basically, learn jQuery.  That's how you do that.